# Datetime not working (php+html)

Tags: php, html, date, datetime, time

I have problem with datetime input ... In HTML code I add datetime but its showing just regular form...
I will post some pictures for u to beter understand what i mean...
This is html code:

```
<form method='post'>
<br>Sport:<br>
<select name='sport'>
<option value='football' selected>Football</option>
<option value='basketball'>Basketball</option>
<option value='tennis'>Tennis</option>
<option value='hockey'>Hockey</option>
<option value='handball'>Handball</option>
<option value='volleyball'>Volleyball</option>
<option value='baseball'>Baseball</option>
<option value='waterpolo'>Water polo</option>
<option value='other'>Other</option>
</select>
<br>Starting time:<br>
<input type='datetime' name='start'/>
<br>Home:<br>
<input type='text' name='home'/><br>
Away:<br>
<input type='text' name='away'/><br>
Pick:<br>
<input type='text' name='pick'/><br>
Odd:<br>
<input type='number' step='0.01' name='odd'/><br>
Stake:<br>
<input type='number' step='0.01' name='stake'/><br>
Analysis:
<br><textarea style='width:100%;' rows='20' name='analiza'></textarea>
<input type='submit' value='Place a bet' name='postavi'/>
</form>
```

But datetime look like this :

[image]

And i dont want to look like this , i want regular datetime witch look like this :

[image]

Thanks everyone who try to help . 
Cheers , Toni.

Comment: What browser you are testing on? [See Browser support](http://caniuse.com/input-datetime)

Comment: You need a javascript plugin to provide that functionality.  Either your own or a third party (I recommend a third party for something standard like this).  I use jQuery and jQuery UI Datepicker buy YMMV

Comment: am testing in chrome and firefox

Comment: Adam, can u please explain me how i can do it , because I am a novice in all of this and i always try to stay away  of javascripts because they look too complicated for me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `datepicker` function that is part of the jQueryUI libray

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/1768/

[jQuery UI link](https://jqueryui.com/)

The is also the HTML5 `date` type attribute. This heavily relies on HTML browser support though.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/1769/

```
 <input type="date" />
```

Comment: Vector, can u please explain me how i can do it , I almost never use javascripts . Thanks.

Comment: I have edited my answer with the `date` HTML5 browser input type. It does depend on what browsers you need to support as regards the best way forward. Personally I use jQuery UI date picker instead of relying on HTML5 due to browser support.

Comment: @user3511855 you simply include the jQuery library and jquery UI library in the head of you html. And then simply add the class of `datepicker` to any html input that you wish to use as a calender type datepicker.

Comment: Just one more question . I just add  datepicker and its working but its showing only to pick a date. Is there option to pick a time also . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Some browser have implemented datetime but then removed it (not sure why). To see which browsers support DateTime input check [caniuse.com/input-datetime](http://caniuse.com/input-datetime)

Edit: use javascript plugin like [JQuery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Example from Jquery page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Almis, can u please explain me how i can use JQuery Datepicker in my code ? I almost never use Jquery and js. thanks

Comment: @StevenPHP I just added the source because OP asked me, I don't copy pasting other answers

Comment: is there option to pick time also ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the `datetime-local`type instead.
So the HTML would look like this:

```
<input type='datetime-local' name='start'/>
```